# Git rebase and push instead of pull

Tags: git

Alternative for 
 1. git pull origin master
 2. git add -a
 3. git commit -m 'message'
 4. git push

How can I do the above without using a pull and using a rebase
 1. git rebase master
 2. git add -a
 3. git commit -m 'message'
 4. git push

Is that all I need to do or am I missing anything. I want to use rebase to have a linear history.

Comment: [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) is a shortcut for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. They do different things and while `git merge` can be replaced by `git rebase` (with different but similar results), [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) cannot be replaced by anything.

Answer (score 0):

## The simple way:

There is a `--rebase` option on `git pull`:

```
git pull -r
```

or

```
git pull --rebase=true
```

## automate it

If you want to rebase on every pull, you can enter the following command:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

If you just want to rebase every `git push` in one repository, execute

```
git config --local pull.rebase true
```

## What happens when doing that?

Actually, `git pull` is the same thing as `git fetch;git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

Knowing this, you can do a rebase instead of a merge:

```
git fetch
git rebase FETCH_HEAD
git add -a
git commit -m 'message'
git push
```

See [the docs for `git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

Answer (score 0):

You can use rebase on pull like so:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

Or on demand:

```
git pull --rebase
```